# AJAX using fetch() resulting in Plug.CSRFProtection error with Phoenix Framework

Tags: ajax, phoenix-framework

I'm replacing jQuery AJAX (that is working ok) with native API `fetch()` but I'm getting an error:

```
Plug.CSRFProtection.InvalidCSRFTokenError) invalid CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) token, make sure all requests include a valid '_csrf_token' param or 'x-csrf-token' header
```

I found this: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1902
but it isn't solving it.
My (simplified) code is:

```
var csrf = this.closest('.formClient.main').querySelector('.csrf').value;
fetch('contacts', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                'x-csrf-token': csrf,
                                'credentials': 'same-origin'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                            message: {name: value, phone: value1, email: value3}
                    })
        })
```

I know the issue is not due to the token itself because this works with the jQuery version of AJAX.
I tested this using Safari and Firefox and got the same error.

Comment: Can you add `alert(csrf)` and confirm that it has a value and is not empty?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, I did it and also inspected the request headers using the network tab on inspector tools and the token is there and is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was placing `credentials: "same-origin"` inside the headers and it is a different option, so it should be:

```
var csrf = this.closest('.formClient.main').querySelector('.csrf').value;
fetch('contacts', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                'x-csrf-token': csrf
                    },
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                            message: {name: value, phone: value1, email: value3}
                    })
        })
```